# calculating the length of a yarn ball

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If I want to calculate the length of a string that is wrapped around a cylinder what mathematical equations can I use? The thread is tightly wrapped around the cylinder, creating a spiral that has no gaps between each consecutive loop. Moreover each complete spiral creates one layer. and as a single layer finishes at the end another start to form up to the top creating a second layer, and so on. The catch is, is that each consecutive layer would require a larger length of string than the one before it because the circumference enlarges. Since the yarn ball is manufactured by machine, it leaves no room for error because the machine is in the same constant motion, the gaps between each string, as well as the gaps between each layer, are all the same, as is the tightness of each loop around the centre cylinder that holds the yarn together. So, how would you suggest I calculate the length using only external measurements and observations?

Comment: You should pick a model that suits your need. A simple model can be consecutive cylindrical layers, each is having the same thickness as yarn/string.

Comment: Another might be to look at volumes (taking into account the cross-sectional shape of the string)

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:[image]

There is no trigonometry or calculus here, only simple volume calculation.

Giving a sketch with no explanations, but leave you to guess the symbol meanings to get you started.

An approximate estimate based on spindle and yarn volumes $ (D,d,L) $ cavity dimensions :

Assume a packing factor approximately for  $ k\text{ in the range} (~ 0.7 ~, 0.8 )$

$$ n = \frac{\pi/4 \cdot (D^2-d^2)L}{k \cdot \pi/4 \cdot d_{yarn}^2}\cdot \pi (D+d)/2$$